# iOS External Accessory Framework: how to get a protocol string for certain MFI device

Tags: ios, external-accessory, ios-bluetooth

I'm writing an iOS application for communicating with mini mPlay Drumi MP18B (a small Bluetooth loudspeaker). As far as I know, `showBluetoothAccessoryPickerWithNameFilter` displays only devices with protocol strings added to Supported External Accessory Protocols key of Info.plist. So I need to add this protocol string to a list.

Where can I get a protocol string for this certain device? Is there a list of device supported protocols anywhere in an internet? Most of manufactures doesn't mention this information in their technical specifications.

Apple refer this protocol string (or ID) in a documentation:

> The picker displays only Bluetooth devices that include an iAP over Bluetooth unique ID in their extended inquiry response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `showBluetoothAccessoryPickerWithNameFilter` only displays devices that are MFi ("Made for iPhone/iPod/iPad") compliant. This means the manufacturer of the device  has to join the the MFi program and certify the device.
If the device is not MFi certified, the only way to connect is through the Apple Bluetooth menu.

If the device is MFi certified, and you are creating an app for the app store, you need to register with the manufacturer to receive a PPId (Product Plan Id). Without the PPId your app will not be approved by Apple.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15146309/4467787